# Allow user to change all the passwords on the host

Tags: linux, passwd

How can I give some user, e.g. jack, permission to edit all the passwords for all users on a host? I have added `jack ALL=/bin/passwd  /etc/shadow  ALL`  in /etc/sudoers file (alternatively using `visudo` ). It says you this user can not use /bin/passwd kate. So I have allowed /bin/passwd, but not 'kate', that's why it's complaining. Is there any solution, guys?

Comment: This `sudo` line is to put it mildly wrong. Secondly, this user may lock the root account out.

Comment: You are confusing commands, arguments, files and users. They are 4 different things.

Comment: Consider what do you want `jack` to be able to do? Run `/bin/passwd` as `root` with any arguments with/without password.

Comment: If the user can change all the passwords, they can change the root password, `su -`, and do everything else as well. Either give them full `sudo` rights or do something else, because this sounds like a textbook [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Actually you can set up sudo to allow to change the passwords for all users except root.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov we can, but how?